# Force git to push different branches to different repos

Tags: git

Let's say I have two local branches: master & dev. I want to force all pushes on the master branch to a repo called master and all pushes on dev to different one called dev.

Why? Because I want to maintain two continuous integration environments, one for each repo.

What I *really* want to do is make sure the master repo rejects all branches other than master and vice-versa. It's fundamental that I don't inadvertently push the wrong branch to the wrong repo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git branch dev --set-upstream dev/dev
```

to define the default upstream location.

This will not fully guard you but if you use "push" without parameter it should go to the right remote branch.

Avoid pushing with "+" or --force could help too. If the server uses something like gitolite do not grant the "+" privilege to you user. This would deny non fast-forward pushes.

Comment: Very interesting, tks. What would be really cool is finding a way to make the remote reject any branches other than the one its configured for. That way the user realizes the mistake and pushes to the right branch.

Comment: As far as i know git is not sending any information about the local branch name to the server on a normal push. The server has no chance to make the decision. On the git mailing list there was a patch suggestion for a pre-push hook that could solve the problem on the client side, but i do not know if/when this will be included in git.

Comment: I suppose I could "redefine" push (ie put it earlier in my $PATH) to simply call git push with no arguments and then use your solution. That way I would always be pushing to the right repo...